# Ngrx store with no reducer? Only to dispatch an action to be catch by an effect

Tags: ngrx

I want my page to dispatch an action on the `ngOnInit`, this action will be catch by an effect and the effect will `this.router.navigate(['path'])` to a new path.

I don't need any reducer here.

But I cannot manage to make it work since `this.store.dispatch()` will only work if I inject my store as a DI and type it as my current state like so `private store: State<fromReducers.State>`

My module as imported the store like so :

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forChild([
      { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', component: EvaluationContainer }
    ]),
    StoreModule.forFeature('evaluation', {}),
    EffectsModule.forFeature(Effects)
  ],
  declarations: [EvaluationContainer]
})
export class FeatureEvaluationModule {}

How can I still dispatch the action in this situation?

Thanks!
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to import `StoreModule.forRoot()` in the parent module. If it is your root module, then here. The `StoreModule.forFeature('evaluation', {})` part you can skip here.

That's how I do the same: https://take.ms/ZXxOx